# how to avoid page postback on dropdown selected index changed

Tags: asp.net

i have bind some dynamic data on selected index changed of dropdown,but when i click on submit button on page postback,data which was bound is gone.
As data is bind on selected index changed of dropdown,if(!(IsPostback)) is not working for me?

Can you please tell how to solve this problem?Plz help

Thanks.
Tina

Comment: please show your code. edit this question and add what you have done.

Comment: If you have viewstate enabled then the drop down list should still be the value you selected after postback. In which case, you can check if(IsPagePostback), then check the value of the dropdown and rebind the data depending on that value, all in the Page_Load event

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can bind your dropdown control once only (i.e. only when IsPostBack is false) is to rely on the view state to maintain the list of items.

It sounds like the view state is not enabled on your drop down control (property EnableViewState). If that is not the problem, please consider posting your code here as the other commenters have requested, so the question can be useful to others.